# How to LIMIT concurrent (parallel) browser requests in Chrome?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, proxy, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

**Background**

I've noticed that almost all proxy providers have the concept of "**Maximum threads**" allowed, which from my understanding means maximum number of concurrent/parallel browser requests at a time.
Since a modern website can have many parallel requests, how can I put a limit in Chrome on parallel requests (globally for the entire browser, not only per host/server, but for all of them combined)?

**Example**

Website A is getting resources from its own domain, and besides that uses 9 CDNs and 10 trackers. Let's say Chrome has max 6 concurrent requests / domain, so that's 120 concurrent requests. Anything above this has to wait its turn. I would like to limit this to a maximum of 10 for example.

**Notes**

I've seen that in Firefox it can be done with '***[network.http.max-connections](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.max-connections)***' but I didn't manage to find anything for Chrome or Chromium.

I'm using Selenium and ChromeDriver (C#) to launch the browser, if it helps.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: @SergeRogatch unfortunately no.

Answer (score 5):

after some digging and searching i found out that for Chromium Many of network tune parameters are in `ClientSocketPoolManager` [check lines : 29 and 46](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:net/socket/client_socket_pool_manager.cc), So i think You will need to rebuild your own custom Chrome with your preferred parameter rather than be able to dynamically tune them.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This parameter could be moved to the command line, rather than just rebuilding the Chrome with another constant. But I can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

### Browser connection limitations

Browsers limit the number of HTTP connections with the same domain name. This restriction is defined in the [HTTP specification (RFC2616)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616). Most modern browsers allow six connections per domain. Most older browsers allow only two connections per domain.

---

### The HTTP/1.1 RFC

The [Section 8.1.4 of the HTTP/1.1 RFC](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec8.html#sec8.1.4) mentions that:

> Clients that use persistent connections SHOULD limit the number of simultaneous connections that they maintain to a given server. A single-user client SHOULD NOT maintain more than 2 connections with any server or proxy. A proxy SHOULD use up to 2*N connections to another server or proxy, where N is the number of simultaneously active users. These guidelines are intended to improve HTTP response times and avoid congestion.

Modern browsers are less restrictive than this allowing a larger number of connections. The RFC does not specify how to prevent the limit being exceeded. Either connections can be blocked from opening or existing connections can be closed.

---

### Settings for Current Browsers

Steve Souders in his article [Roundup on Parallel Connections](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/03/20/roundup-on-parallel-connections/) provided the number of connections per server supported by current browsers for HTTP/1.1 as well as HTTP/1.0 which is as follows:

```
Browser                 HTTP/1.1    HTTP/1.0
IE 6,7                  2           4
IE 8                    6           6
Firefox 2               2           8
Firefox 3               6           6
Safari 3,4              4           4
Chrome 1,2              6           ?
Chrome 3                4           4
Chrome 4+               6           ?
iPhone 2                4           ?
iPhone 3                6           ?
iPhone 4                4           ?
Opera 9.63,10.00alpha   4           4
Opera 10.51+            8           ?
```

It is possible to reconfigure your browser tweaking the `MaxConnectionsPerServer` and `MaxConnectionsPer1_0Server` settings in the *Windows Registry* control the number of connections per hostname for `HTTP/1.1` and `HTTP/1.0` respectively.

In Firefox these values can be controlled by the [network.http.max-connections](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.max-connections) and [network.http.max-connections-per-server](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server) settings in `about:config`.

Now to [Match Firefox's per-host connection limit of 15](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=12066) Chromium/Chrome team tried to match the same and went through the discussion [Configurable connections-per-host](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=85323) but ended up without any conclusions.

---

### Conclusion

The same standards are also applicable while you use any of the *WebDriver* and *Web Browser* variant combo. The behavior with *Selenium Grid Setup*, *Chrome Headless* and *Firefox Headless* will also be identical.

---

### References

- [Increasing Google Chrome's max-connections-per-server limit to more than 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404464/increasing-google-chromes-max-connections-per-server-limit-to-more-than-6)
- [How to solve Chrome's 6 connection limit when using xhr polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32697909/how-to-solve-chromes-6-connection-limit-when-using-xhr-polling)
- [Max parallel http connections in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, in the shortest form, how to limit to 1 the number of simultaneous connections from a browser.

Comment: Not only does it not answer the question but it also uses URLs from 2008