# Multiple api requests to the same domain produce slower response time

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, fetch, google-chrome-devtools

I am using native fetch at the google chrome browser. Trying to send multiple API requests to the same domain.

```
const parallel = 100
Promise.all(Array(parallel).fill('').map(() => fetch(url, {method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(data) })))
```

`data` variable by itself is about 41802kb.

Debugging network, I realize that `Request sent` takes the longest time
[image]

Comparing the same requests but when `parallel=10`
[image]

Anything I can do to improve this? The same behaviour with nodejs using the `node-fetch` package. Is there any solution to run multiple requests to the same domain in parallel without loosing fast response time?

Comment: Do you have control of the API, might you be rate limited at 100 requests?  A lot of 3rd party API's will rate limit calls to stop a potential DDOS

Comment: no, i don't. i have tried to point on my local http server which accepts request and simply respond with http code 200. result the same

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55973968/how-to-limit-concurrent-parallel-browser-requests-in-chrome#:~:text=Website%20A%20is%20getting%20resources%20from%20its%20own,this%20to%20a%20maximum%20of%2010%20for%20example.

I think this will help you... Chrome limits the amount of connections to the same domain.  Try running the same test but without chrome

Comment: those limitations related to http1. api server which i use supports http2. moreover, in nodejs i have the same

Comment: might be worth adding these details into your original post.

Comment: Also, not 100% sure the built in fetch API handles HTTP2, you might need a library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-h2, but as i say i'm not 100% sure

Answer (score 0):

when you lost fast response time in parallel requests to the same domain,
it depends on many factors
for example, you should find a bottleneck here,

1 - the internet speed

2 - the API server downstream speed

3 - ratio control and DDoS control on API server

etc ...

for checking the internet speed you could check your bandwidth
and deploy some local HTTP server and send parallel requests and compare the result
as I know its very rarely the problem was from client code, commonly its depends on items that said

Comment: I have tried to create local HTTP server which simply accepts request and response with status code 200. the same result

Comment: whats your data has been served in your local HTTP server /

Comment: it's an array of json https://gist.github.com/fireridlle/db9fae6e29b50f254768bfab09a790f7

Comment: whats you local http server ?

Comment: ```
const http = require('http')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5001

const server = http.createServer(async (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  res.write(JSON.stringify({ resource: 1 }))
  res.end()
})

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`server started on port: ${PORT}`)
})
```

Comment: could you put nginx cache top of you local HTTP server?